# Adjusting GPS location of an object (sled) pulled at a set distance as it moves 3D

Tags: qgis, mathematics

A bit of an odd question.

We're pulling a sled behind a truck which carries an instrument. We've had to mount the GPS on the truck and are pulling the instrument back and forth in lines in a field. We want to know the actual location of the instrument.

The sled is at a set distance from the truck (2.5m) as its pulled. But because we're moving it back and forth, we can't just shift the GPS location of the sled.

Currently, we've been adjusting the location using a b-spline, but I'm wondering if there's an easier/better way in QGIS (or even mathematically) to find the location of the sled.

Comment: Depending on the GPS Model, there is normally a setting for either antenna or an horizontal offset that can be applied at the source. like page 15 https://www.uvm.edu/giv/resources/TrimbleGPS_wTerraSync_0.pdf

Comment: Ardupilot has also such settings https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-sensor-offset-compensation.html

Comment: Is your GPS good enough that 2.5m would make a difference? Cheap GPS units tend to have a lot of variance, really cheap ones could place you location with 10 metre uncertainty; really good GPS wouldn't like bouncing around on a truck so much. You could use 'lever arm adjustment' and assume that the sled is directly behind the truck (it usually is) but that can in no way account for the swing/flex of the sled relative to the truck.

Comment: Maybe you should mount compasses into your sled or tractor and utilize the signal for offsetting the GPS points 2.5 m towards desired direction mathematically.

Comment: 1. The program we're using (it's a specific data logger with the equipment) does not have an option for offset. 

2. The GPS is good enough - sub-cm. It is supposed to be rugged (an Emlid RS2).

3. Interesting idea on cmopass. Have to think of it more.